# How can I convert a foreach loop to a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

```
foreach (var item in pList)
{
    if (item.PDate> Calendar.GetAppDate() && dtoPP.pLastDate < item.pLastDate)
    {
        dtoPP= item;
    }
}
```

i try to do that way, but where can i do assingment ( dtoPP= item;) that part?

```
pList.Where(item => item.PDate> Calendar.GetAppDate() && dtoPP.pLastDate < item.pLastDate ).ToList();
```

Comment: You may want to cache `Calendar.GetAppDate()` , though.

Comment: something like this  `item.Where(your condition).ForEach(x=> dtoPP = x);`

Comment: Am I correct: You want to find the latest element (determined by `pLastDate`) in `pList` that has `PDate` later than `Calendar.GetAppDate()` ? And then you want to assign that element to `dtoPP`. Is that correct?

Comment: `dtoPP = pList.Where(item => item.PDate> Calendar.GetAppDate).OrderByDescending(item => item.pLastDate).FirstrOrDefault();`

Comment: @Fildor, yep, that is right.

Answer (score 3):

To find the last item with a `PDate` greater than `Calendar.GetAppDate()` you can use the following query (assuming `PDate` and `pLastDate` are `DateTime`, or other comparable types):

```
var appDate = Calendar.GetAppDate();
var latestItem = pList
    .Where(i => i.PDate > appDate) // filter out any items where PDate <= appDate
    .OrderBy(i => i.pLastDate) // sort by pLastDate ascending (oldest to newest)
    .LastOrDefault(); // get the last item or default (null for reference types)
```

Note that I am caching the result of `Calendar.GetAppDate();` so as to avoid evaluating it repeatedly as we go through `pList`.

Answer (score -2):

Here are two ways that could work. (UNTESTED)

```
var result = pList.LastOrDefault(item => item.PDate > Calendar.GetAppDate() && dtoPP.pLastDate < item.pLastDate);
```

```
var result = pList.Where(item => item.PDate > Calendar.GetAppDate() && dtoPP.pLastDate < item.pLastDate).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: The equivalent would be `LastOrDefault` since the loop keeps going past the first match.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the LINQ Max method to find the element in pList with the maximum value of pLastDate, where PDate is greater than Calendar.GetAppDate():

```
dtoPP = pList.Where(i => i.PDate > Calendar.GetAppDate())
             .Max(i => i.pLastDate);
```

Comment: Again: I'd cache that `GetAppDate()` call. (I did not DV)

Comment: `dtoPP` is the item type.

Comment: The code takes the last match, not the match with a max value (unless the list is sorted which we don't know)